# SQL: aggregate function or the GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is an sql statement and an error I'm receiving. I have included all the possible fields from both tables, what is wrong? I want to group all returned items by the prodID

Column 'orders.adminStatus' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

```
 SELECT TOP 20 
         ADMINSTATUS,   CURRENCY,   CUSTOMERID,     CUSTOMERMESSAGE,    DELTIME,    DELTOTAL,   DISCOUNT,   DISCOUNTCODE,   
         IP,    ITEMDES,    OPTIONS,    ORDEREDID,  ORDERTOTAL,
         oi.ORDER_ID,   o.ORDER_ID,     PAYMENTTYPE,    PPRICE,     PRODID,     QTY,    REASON,     SECURITYKEY,    SHIPADDRESS1,   
         SHIPADDRESS2,  SHIPADDRESS3,   SHIPCITY,   SHIPCOMPANY,    
         SHIPCOUNTRY,   SHIPCOUNTY,     SHIPMETHOD,
         SHIPNAME,  SHIPPOSTCODE,   STATUS,     STOCKCODE,  SUBTOTAL,   TAX,    TAXABLE,    TIMEDATE,   TXAUTHNO,   VENDORTXCODE,   VPSTXID
         FROM orderedItems oi
         left join orders o on  oi.order_id = o.order_id


    Group by PRODID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are selecting separate columns, they ALL need to appear in the GROUP BY clause unless they are aggregate functions.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 20 
         ADMINSTATUS,   CURRENCY,   CUSTOMERID,     CUSTOMERMESSAGE,    DELTIME,    DELTOTAL,   DISCOUNT,   DISCOUNTCODE,   
         IP,    ITEMDES,    OPTIONS,    ORDEREDID,  ORDERTOTAL,
         oi.ORDER_ID,   o.ORDER_ID,     PAYMENTTYPE,    PPRICE,     PRODID,     QTY,    REASON,     SECURITYKEY,    SHIPADDRESS1,   
         SHIPADDRESS2,  SHIPADDRESS3,   SHIPCITY,   SHIPCOMPANY,    
         SHIPCOUNTRY,   SHIPCOUNTY,     SHIPMETHOD,
         SHIPNAME,  SHIPPOSTCODE,   STATUS,     STOCKCODE,  SUBTOTAL,   TAX,    TAXABLE,    TIMEDATE,   TXAUTHNO,   VENDORTXCODE,   VPSTXID
         FROM orderedItems oi
         left join orders o on  oi.order_id = o.order_id


    Group by ADMINSTATUS,   CURRENCY,   CUSTOMERID,     CUSTOMERMESSAGE,    DELTIME,    DELTOTAL,   DISCOUNT,   DISCOUNTCODE,   
         IP,    ITEMDES,    OPTIONS,    ORDEREDID,  ORDERTOTAL,
         oi.ORDER_ID,   o.ORDER_ID,     PAYMENTTYPE,    PPRICE,     PRODID,     QTY,    REASON,     SECURITYKEY,    SHIPADDRESS1,   
         SHIPADDRESS2,  SHIPADDRESS3,   SHIPCITY,   SHIPCOMPANY,    
         SHIPCOUNTRY,   SHIPCOUNTY,     SHIPMETHOD,
         SHIPNAME,  SHIPPOSTCODE,   STATUS,     STOCKCODE,  SUBTOTAL,   TAX,    TAXABLE,    TIMEDATE,   TXAUTHNO,   VENDORTXCODE,   VPSTXID
```

Answer (score 2):

Because, as it says, if you are using GROUP BY, you either need to group by the field you are returning, or apply an aggregate function to it; eg: MAX, MIN, etc

```
SELECT TOP 20  
         ADMINSTATUS,   CURRENCY,   CUSTOMERID,     CUSTOMERMESSAGE,    DELTIME,    DELTOTAL,   DISCOUNT,   DISCOUNTCODE,    
         IP,    ITEMDES,    OPTIONS,    ORDEREDID,  ORDERTOTAL, 
         oi.ORDER_ID,   o.ORDER_ID,     PAYMENTTYPE,    PPRICE,     PRODID,     QTY,    REASON,     SECURITYKEY,    SHIPADDRESS1,    
         SHIPADDRESS2,  SHIPADDRESS3,   SHIPCITY,   SHIPCOMPANY,     
         SHIPCOUNTRY,   SHIPCOUNTY,     SHIPMETHOD, 
         SHIPNAME,  SHIPPOSTCODE,   STATUS,     STOCKCODE,  SUBTOTAL,   TAX,    TAXABLE,    TIMEDATE,   TXAUTHNO,   VENDORTXCODE,   VPSTXID 
         FROM orderedItems oi 
         left join orders o on  oi.order_id = o.order_id 



Group by          ADMINSTATUS,   CURRENCY,   CUSTOMERID,     CUSTOMERMESSAGE,    DELTIME,    DELTOTAL,   DISCOUNT,   DISCOUNTCODE,    
     IP,    ITEMDES,    OPTIONS,    ORDEREDID,  ORDERTOTAL, 
     oi.ORDER_ID,   o.ORDER_ID,     PAYMENTTYPE,    PPRICE,     PRODID,     QTY,    REASON,     SECURITYKEY,    SHIPADDRESS1,    
     SHIPADDRESS2,  SHIPADDRESS3,   SHIPCITY,   SHIPCOMPANY,     
     SHIPCOUNTRY,   SHIPCOUNTY,     SHIPMETHOD, 
     SHIPNAME,  SHIPPOSTCODE,   STATUS,     STOCKCODE,  SUBTOTAL,   TAX,    TAXABLE,    TIMEDATE,   TXAUTHNO,   VENDORTXCODE,   VPSTXID
```

Comment: +1 Looks like we both wrote the same thing, so I guess I have to vote for your answer! :-)

Comment: I think it probably means we both write a fair bit of SQL for a living :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are grouping by  PRODID, in the select list only  PRODID should be present, If you want any other columns in the select list, it should be given with aggregate finction like AVG(), MIN() MAX() etc..

If you group by all the columns available in the table, it is equal to

```
select distinct * from table
```

Usually GROUP BY is used with aggregate functions to get MIN,MAX,etc for each group in a table

[GROUP BY examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: You don't have to show the fields you're grouping by, although that may be a red herring in this case.

Comment: @podiluska: What I mean is, other than PRODID you cannot give anything in the select list, though PRODID is optional in the select list